# React-native Name Collision without Pod

Tags: ios, react-native

i followed the instruction and successfully created a project called ReactNative, when i open it with Xcode 7.2 & run, it always shows below error, plz help !

```
Error building DependencyGraph:
Error: Naming collision detected: /Users/johnny/Documents/drafts/ReactNative/package.json collides with /Users/johnny/Documents/drafts/ReactNative/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/ReactNative.js
at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (HasteMap.js:132:13)
at HasteMap.js:112:32
at tryCallOne (/Users/johnny/Documents/drafts/ReactNative/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
at /Users/johnny/Documents/drafts/ReactNative/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
at flush (/Users/johnny/Documents/drafts/ReactNative/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ReactNative@0.0.1 start: node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ReactNative@0.0.1 start script 'node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ReactNative package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls ReactNative
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Users/johnny/Documents/drafts/ReactNative/npm-debug.log
```

and below is all the versions info

```
react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.18.1

$ node -v
v5.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The name ReactNative is already used by react-native. Try again with another name.